# Calculate the gps coordinates of sides of street on a map

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

[image]

I have the GPS co ordinate of the user on a map (Indicated by red dot in the picture)

I would like to calculate the GPS co ordinates of the blue dots on the map.

The dots are equidistant from the red dot on either side. If I can get the heading of the street compared to magnetic north I can calculate the dots or is there any other easy way?

Comment: A valid question, solveable as shown below, I am quite sure that None of the "Put on Hold Voters" are able to solve this task.

Comment: @AlexWien thanks That was my thought. Anyway, I managed another way as well and will update it when I get time.

Comment: I solved this task for my job, its a combination of school geometry and considering that latitude and longitude are not cartesian coordinates (you want to transform to caretsian first)

Comment: how did you solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I tested it use [map version 1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/package-summary), not map api V2.)

Before follow steps, you should know distance and angle before finding coordinates.

Steps:

1. Change geo point to pixel(x, y). (Use [projection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection))
2. Get pixel size of distance(d). (Use [metersToEquatorPixels](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection#metersToEquatorPixels%28float%29))
3. Then you get a point (d, 0)
4. Rotate (d,0) ==> You will get a new point which spaced apart at d from (0, 0) ==> (a, b)
5. (x+a, b+y) is a point that you want.
6. Get geo coordinate of (x+a, y+b) use [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection#fromPixels%28int,%20int%29).

Rotation formular is

```
(x'*cos(θ) - y'*sin(θ), x'*sin(θ) + y'*cos(θ))
```

so, you can change this simple.

```
(d*cos(θ), d*sin(θ)) // This is a point of step 4. (a,b)
```

My code is.

```
// you should know distance and angle

Point px = new Point();
Point px2 = new Point();

mapView.getProjection().toPixels(mGeoPt, px);
float pixedDis = mapView.getProjection().metersToEquatorPixels(distance);

px2.x = (int)(pixedDis*Math.cos(angle)) + px.x;
px2.y = (int)(pixedDis*Math.sin(angle)) + px.y;

GeoPoint gp3 = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(px2.x, px2.y);
```